# Use of undeclared var from a namespace, but the var exists

Tags: namespaces, clojurescript, reitit

I have this def in myapp.core (core.cljs):

```
(def router 
    (reitit/router [["/" {:name :foo :view #'foo}]])
)
```

And in myapp.events (events.cljs), I use it like so:

```
{:dispatch [:common/navigate (reitit/match-by-path myapp.core/router "/browse")]}
```

But I get the error:

```
{:dispatch [:common/navigate (reitit/match-by-path myapp.core/router "/browse")]
--------------------------------------------------------------------^-----------
 Use of undeclared Var myapp.core/router
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1385 |            }
```

Why would that be?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the full name `myapp.core/router` I assume you don't have a proper require for that namespace in your `ns` form.

You must have `(:require [myapp.core])` in that ns, preferably with an `:as` alias and using that. It is not allowed to "cheat" by using the full name.